# huge size library not loading in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I have ported a library (ice , NAT traversal ) for iPhone and encountering issue while actually testing it on iphone device(Version 4.3). Developed a cocoa touch wrapper which is linked with my library. The library routines get called from "test" button placed in my application.

The application is .mm and library is C++ based.

Below are the cases in which my application fails/passes

Case I: I "build and debug" / "build and run" application from Xcode for iphone. The application works fine on iphone and I am able to see logs for the same on the console on my mac machine.

Case II: I try to run application from my iphone, but it just crashes while opening.

Case III: I build and debug application from Xcode, the application get's launched. But as soon as i unplug the debug cable (attached to iphone from my mac), the application get's crashed.

The size of application is 16 MB, and size of library is 288 MB.

I tried to simulate same issue by making a simple test application and a test library. it runs fine in all cases without issues. What can be the issue?

1. It seems that the application is mapping library code from mac machine while running on iphone. and once the physical link is broken, the app crashes.
2. size of library is huge?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to add, I ran otools -L to confirm the dependency, all the binaries are for arm6 and arm7 architecture.

Comment: Do you get a stack trace? 288MB of compiled code is a lot. I bet this is memory related. Have you tried breaking the lib down in smaller pieces and only load the parts you actually use?

Comment: 1. The application works fine on iphone when debug cable is attached to the iphone through mac os x. The application doesnot work when i detach the cable. so i cannot see stack trace at that time.

Comment: 2. Also the library code will only be executed on click of the button. So i donot think there should be memory issues at that time. To test it i added a dummy function returning a integer. i only called that function from my application. still the same issue.

Comment: can this be timing issue related? when we run app through mac os, we are actually giving it lot of time to load things.. but it is not the case when we run it directly from iOS..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS kills apps that blocks the main thread for too long. So that may be the problem and also explains why the app doesn't get killed in debug mode.

Try running your function in the background and see if that helps!

Comment: On observing the library code, it has some global variable intaniations which are actually required. This might be actually taking time, which in turn be blocking main thread. So i think we cannot put that code in background. is there any other way to rather make main thread wait instead of breaking down? i read about grand central dispatch, can that be used?

Comment: Running it in the background with `performSelectorInBackground:` should work just fine. You should be using that all the time when you need to do stuff that is heavy. GCD does the same thing so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have few header files in library, which in turn have some global variables. those have to be included. those are actually creating delay for main thread. the functionality to invoke is under a button. so even if i put that function in background (using performselectorinbackground) it won;t help. i tried as u said but that didnot help (reason:as i said, above)

Comment: If that is indeed the case, then should split up initialization into several steps which you push to a background queue and hope the main thread gets a chance to run (or explicitly add a short delay between each initialization step). For that GCD might be a good option.

Comment: any idea how to implement GCD?

Comment: Yes, but that is another, separate, question from this specific problem. The apple docs are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer to my question! Thanks a lot Martin for pointing out "iOS kills apps that blocks the main thread for too long"

Following is the procedure i followed to find the resolve the issue:

Xcode "orgainzer"--> "Device logs" section shows iphone crash report. My application crash report was also generated in the same.

In crash report it was clearly written "mytestapp failed to launch in time" and further it showed the API which was taking too long to return the result. ( in my case it was getlocalhostname API).

I just corrected the API as per my requirement, compiled and run the app on iphone device and it worked!! Also the launch time of application is pretty less now.

Thanks again!